# flutter: Keep playing a webview when navigating to another screen

Tags: flutter, webview

I am developing an app where I have to create a video player, I am doing it with webview, however I need to show that player on different screens, and when browsing, keep the playback within the webview even when navigating to another screen.
Could someone tell me how to keep the reproduction within a webview when navigating from one screen to another?